# Using scikit-learn's SGDClassifier to implement SVM: how to tune the regularization parameter?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am using `scikit-learn` library to implement SVM for a large-size dataset (300-400K samples with <100 features). To cope with the size issue, I am using `SGDClassifier` rather than `libsvm`, however I am not aware of any argument/parameter so that I can tune the regularization parameter within `SGDClassifier`. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks,
Soheil

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the arguments - penalty and alpha. 
And l1_ratio if you consider elastic net.

Look at this

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html